# How to defer getAnnotation call to an instance variable's type

Tags: java, annotations

I have an interface

```java
public interface ExportDocumentFactory {
  Class<?>[] getSupportedDataRecordClasses();
}
```

that allows implementing classes to declare types of DataRecords they support

```java
@Override
public Class<?>[] getSupportedDataRecordClasses() {
  Class<?>[] classes = new Class<?>[1];
  classes[0] = CardRequestBatchComponent.class;
  return classes;
}
```

so that a service can read the supported types

```java
sourceClasses = sourceFileClientConfig.getFileFactory().getSupportedDataRecordClasses();
```

This work fine, except that I think it could be done better with an annotation, e.g.

```java
@DataRecordSupport({CardRequestBatchComponent.class})
```

which looks like

```java
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface DataRecordSupport {
  Class<?>[] value() default {};
}
```

and is read like

```java
sourceClasses = sourceFileClientConfig.getFileFactory().getClass().getAnnotation(DataRecordSupport.class).value();
```

But there's a complication. One of the implementing classes is a facade, so that it overrides like so

```java
@Override
public Class<?>[] getSupportedDataRecordClasses() {
  return config.getFileFactory().getSupportedDataRecordClasses();
}
```

The getAnnotation method above will fail to find any annotation on objects of this class. How can I get this to work, preferably without changing the caller?

If I did change the caller to only work with this one class, I would first have to create the getConfig getter, and then make it

```java
sourceClasses = sourceFileClientConfig.getFileFactory().getConfig().getFileFactory().getClass().getAnnotation(DataRecordSupport.class).value();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make `getSupportedDataRecordClasses()` a default method, and then have it responsible for reading the annotation from the class. That way the facade can still override the method to call the "real" method, while letting the "real" method continue to be based on the annotation (without having to implement the same thing for every `ExportDocumentFactory` implementation).

For example:

```java
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

public interface ExportDocumentFactory {
    
    default Class<?>[] getSupportedDataRecordClasses() {
        var annotation = getClass().getAnnotation(DataRecordSupport.class);
        if (annotation == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("no DataRecordSupport annotation present");
        }
        return annotation.value();
    }
    
    @Inherited
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target(ElementType.TYPE)
    @interface DataRecordSupport {

        Class<?>[] value() default {};
    }
}
```

---

Note this is similar to what [`AbstractProcessor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/annotation/processing/AbstractProcessor.html) does with e.g., [`SupportedAnnotationTypes`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/annotation/processing/SupportedAnnotationTypes.html).

Comment: is it possible to restrict to `Class<DataRecord>`? Even though ImportRecord extends DataRecord I'm unable to `@DataRecordSupport({ImportRecord.class})`

Comment: Make the return types `Class<? extends DataRecord>[]`. That will work without issue for the most part, especially if you stick with the annotation approach. Just note that arrays and generics don't work together the best. So, if you override `getSupportedDataRecordClasses()` and attempt to create the array "manually", then you'll have to perform a cast and suppress the resulting "unchecked cast" warning.

Comment: Of course, you might consider modifying the interface method to return `List<Class<? extends DataRecord>>` or some other collection type. If you make it a list, then the implementation changes to `return List.of(annotation.value())`. Unfortunately, you'll need to keep using `Class<? extends DataRecord>[]` in the annotation, as only primitives, strings, enums, classes, and arrays of those types are allowed as annotation element types.

Comment: Creating an array manually - that's probably why my prior attempts failed. I actually ended up doing this to satisfy https://errorprone.info/bugpattern/AvoidObjectArrays. Thanks for your help!